# Check if query contains a string in document field

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to check if a document field contains a string that is in the query?

For example:

collection `cities`:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Madrid" }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Lisbon" }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "Paris" }
```

Query:

```
db.cities.find({
    name: {$isIn: 'Address of the street, Lisbon'}
});
```

Result:

```
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Lisbon" }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Take a look at the [`$text` documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#text). Basically you would have to create a text index on the field and then you could search as follows:

```
db.cities.find({ $text: { $search: "Address of the street, Lisbon" } })
```

An example for creating an index in this case. Since your field is called `name`:

```
db.cities.createIndex( { name: "text" } )
```

You have many possibilities such as exclude a phrase, contain only, case sensitive etc.

So lets say I add the following documents:

```
{ "_id" : NumberInt(1), "name" : "Madrid" }
{ "_id" : NumberInt(2), "name" : "Lisbon" }
{ "_id" : NumberInt(3), "name" : "Paris" }
{ "_id" : NumberInt(4), "name" : "Address"}
```

If we'd search like that:

```
db.cities.find({ $text: { $search: "Address of the street, Lisbon" } })
```

we would get 2 results:

```
{ "_id" : NumberInt(2), "name" : "Lisbon"}
{ "_id" : NumberInt(4), "name" : "Address"}
```

But if we'd search like that:

```
db.cities.find({ $text: { $search: "-Address of the street, Lisbon" } })
```

we would only get:

```
{ "_id" : NumberInt(2), "name" : "Lisbon"}
```

because with (-) you can exclude documents that contain this term. For more possibilities check out the documentation

Comment: Thanks. I ended up splitting the query string into a array and use the $in operator.

Comment: for the suitable answer +1

Answer (score 3):

```
db.cities.find({"name" : {$regex : ".*Lisbon.*"}});
```

Yes you can use regex to find some string pattern.

Comment: Can you add the above data in your collection and fire that query it will give you correct answer.

Comment: No... OP want to query by "Address of the street, Lisbon" string